# Loss of control over my computer mouse

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, malware

I've had this strange thing happen to me on 3 separate computers running Windows 10 now (on my work computer at a previous job, on my previous home computer, and now on my work computer at my current job):
I'm doing work on my computer as per usual, and I suddenly lose control over my computer mouse for a few minutes. The mouse moves on its own around the screen and sometimes it even triggers the right mouse click. During this time the computer doesn't respond to either the external mouse movements or the touchpad movements. After those few minutes it all goes back to normal and I regain the control over the mouse. The following can be said for all of these cases/computers:

- the subsequent AV run didn't detect any malware (they were all reputable AVs)
- latest Windows updates were applied
- no software with remote control capabilities (zoom, TeamViewer etc.) was running at the time
- reviewing the currently running processes list didn't flag anything suspicious
- no mouse defects (external/touchpad) were detected

In one of the cases, it also auto-switched between the opened applications (the alt+tab function), and in another, the notifications menu and Cortana menu were popping up on their own. Also the external mouse/touchpad were different each time. Below I'm appending a gif that recreates an approximation of the mouse movements described above, so you've got a better idea of what I mean.

I'm struggling to find a sensible explanation for how come I've encountered this on 3 separate computers now (spread over about 5 years), and am yet to meet anyone who would encounter this kind of a thing at all. Has anyone ran into something like this before, or has a good explanation for it?

[image: Mouse moving on its own]

Comment: Is it always the same mouse or pad?

Comment: No, they were different each time.

Comment: From a computer becoming non-responsive, I've had this occasionally happen when SLACK notifications were enabled. Once I turned it off, then no problem. But that wouldn't explain the random mouse movements. Good luck.

Comment: I've had this happen with mousepads that have a design on them. I tend to just get a solid color mousepad because of that.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not using a pad at all: the mouse is directly on the table.

Comment: Is the table reflective?

Comment: No, the tables were different as well and none was a reflective one.

Comment: Wired or wireless?? If wireless, the answer is IOTETMCO.

Comment: During the last case it was a wired one, but the ones before might've involved wireless, can't remember exactly.